# Count occurance of unique values in a pandas dataframe across multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe in pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a' : ['hello', 'world', 'great', 'hello'], 'b' : ['world', None, 'hello', 'world'], 'c' : [None, 'hello', 'great', None]})
```

i would like to count the occurrence of the unique values in column 'a' across all the other columns and column 'a' too and save that into new columns for the dataframe with appropriate naming that take on the values in column 'a' such as 'hello_count', 'world_count' and so on. Hence the end result would be something like

```
 df = pd.DataFrame({'a' : ['hello', 'world', 'great', 'hello'], 'b' : ['world', None, 'hello', 'world'], 'c' : [None, 'hello', 'great', None], 'hello_count' : [1,1,1,1], 'world_count' : [1,1,0,1], 'great_count' : [0,0,2,0]})
```

i tried

```
df['a', 'b', 'a'].groupby('a').agg(['count])
```

but that did not work. Any help is really appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's use `pd.get_dummies` and `groupby`:

```
(df1.assign(**pd.get_dummies(df1)
                .pipe(lambda x: x.groupby(x.columns.str[2:], axis=1)
                .sum())))
```

Output:

```
       a      b      c  great  hello  world
0  hello  world   None      0      1      1
1  world   None  hello      0      1      1
2  great  hello  great      2      1      0
3  hello  world   None      0      1      1
```

Here is the above solution in steps.

#### Step 1: pd.get_dummies

```
df_gd = pd.get_dummies(df1)
print(df_gd)

   a_great  a_hello  a_world  b_hello  b_world  c_great  c_hello
0        0        1        0        0        1        0        0
1        0        0        1        0        0        0        1
2        1        0        0        1        0        1        0
3        0        1        0        0        1        0        0
```

#### Step 2: groupby column names ignoring the first two letters

```
df_gb = df_gd.groupby(df_gd.columns.str[2:], axis=1).sum()
print(df_gb)

   great  hello  world
0      0      1      1
1      0      1      1
2      2      1      0
3      0      1      1
```

#### Step 3: Join back to original dataframe

```
df_out = df1.join(df_gb)
print(df_out)
```

Ouput:

```
       a      b      c  great  hello  world
0  hello  world   None      0      1      1
1  world   None  hello      0      1      1
2  great  hello  great      2      1      0
3  hello  world   None      0      1      1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That did work but with one more problem though. I used the name for my columns as 'a', 'b', 'c' which all consist of one character but in my real application the naming are different and so the length of the column name is different. I see that you used str[2:] but that is only because the names consist of 1 character. Is there a way to solve this problem

Comment: are then any Underscores in your original columns, you can use split('_').str[1] also to group on.

Comment: well there is an underscore in all the columns but then it could be _1 or _20. The column names are exactly the same but with an incremental prefix that go from 0 to 20. Hence the columns names are for example Address_0 to Address_20.

Comment: Just one, only one, always one?  then you can still use split('_').str[2]

Comment: yep that did work, many thanks for the help. The final solution would be (df.assign(**pd.get_dummies(df[cols_incl])
                              .pipe(lambda x: x.groupby(x.columns.str.split('_').str[2], axis=1).sum())))

Comment: Maybe you can add `df.stack().str.get_dummies().sum(level=0)` :-)

Comment: @Wen Yoh should add that as an answer.

Comment: No need, If I am the visitor I would like see one answer contain all possible solution :-)

Answer (score 0):

Using `df.apply` in a loop simplifies the job. Each row is then tested how many of its elements are same as the required string:

```
for ss in df.a.unique():
    df[ss+"_count"] = df.apply(lambda row: sum(map(lambda x: x==ss, row)), axis=1)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
       a      b      c  hello_count  world_count  great_count
0  hello  world   None            1            1            0
1  world   None  hello            1            1            0
2  great  hello  great            1            0            2
3  hello  world   None            1            1            0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create dictionary d_unique={} and assign all the unique values as key pair in to it, consider the dataframe named as data_rnr:

```
d_unique={}
for col in data_rnr.columns:
    print(data_rnr[col].name)
    print(len(data_rnr[col].unique()))
    d_unique[data_rnr[col].name]=len(data_rnr[col].unique())
```